# Xubuntu 18.04.6 LTS, suddenly I can't connect to the internet via ethernet, getting DNS_PROBE_FINISHED_BAD_CONFIG

Tags: xubuntu, internet

All I did was restart my router.

Everything else connects without a problem, including my Windows 10 partition in another computer.

I tried googling it, and all that came up was some stuff involving resolvconf, which it says I don't have installed.

Can someone please help?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: I would suggest reboot the router again and after it is back up reboot the computer and see if the problem is gone.

Comment: First thing I tried. No change.

Answer (score 1):

I was able to resolve the issue by:

1. Deleting `resolv.conf`:

   ```
   sudo rm /etc/resolv.conf
   ```
2. Restarting Ubuntu

This fixed the problem.